# How to get status of Firebase Realtime Database operation?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a function removeCategory(categoryAddress: String) in my Firebase Repository which removes the given node from Realtime Database and emits the appropriate result String as **Loading**, **Success** or **Some Error occurred: [error_message]** in a flow.
Although the given node gets deleted from the Database successfully I am not receiving **Success** message.

This is my function inside repo:--

```
override fun removeCategory(categoryAddress: String)= flow {
    val response = StatusString()
    realtimeRootRef.child(categoryAddress).ref.removeValue().addOnSuccessListener {
        response.status = "Success"
    }.addOnFailureListener{
        response.status = "Some Error occurred : ${it.message}"
    }
    emit(response)
}
```

And this is my ViewModel code where I am calling that function to remove node = remove_testing :--

```
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.removeCategory("remove_testing").collectLatest {
            Log.d(TAG,"statusString : ${it.status}")
        }
    }
}
```

This is my StatusString class:--

```
data class StatusString(
var status: String = "Loading"
```

)

This is my Logcat:--
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyw9G.png)

The node is getting deleted successfully but I am not able to get the "Success" message in ViewModel. What should I do to receive a success or failure message from the Flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Kotlin, the best option that you have would be to use [Kotlin Coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines) and **not** listeners. So in code, your operation should look like this:

```
fun removeCategory(categoryAddress: String) = flow {
    val response = StatusString()
    try {
        realtimeRootRef.child(categoryAddress).ref.removeValue().await()
        response.status = "Success"
    } catch (it: Exception) {
        response.status = "Some Error occurred : ${it.message}"
    }
    emit(response)
}
```

There are also other ways in which you can achieve that:

- [How to read data from Firebase Realtime Database using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5)